# To understand whether a module is flat, injective or projective through a explicit example

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Suppose a ring $R = \mathbb{C}[x, y]$, An ideal $I = (y^2 − x^3 + x^7)$ and $M = (R/I )_I \oplus (R/I )$. We can easily check that $R/I$ is an integral domain thus $I$ is a Prime Ideal. Hence multiplicative set is $S:=R\backslash I$, thus localization makes sense.
Now I want to determine whether M is flat, projective, or injective .
My guess is to show that $(R/I )_I$ and  $(R/I )$ is flat $R-$module and using the fact that the direct sum of the flat module is flat, thus $M$ is flat.

Are the above arguments correct or I am going in the wrong direction?

Any hint(s), suggestion(s), or help is highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: One important consequence of flatness is to consider multiplication by $x$ on $R$, as a short exact sequence. Then tensoring this with $M$ implies that if $x$ is a non zerodivisor in $R$, and $M$ is flat, then multiplication by $x$ is injective on $M$. This is to say, flatness is related to being torsion free, and if you see torsion in your module (such as $R/I$ as an $R$ module), then your module can’t be flat.

Comment: Since $R/I$ has torsion as $R-$module, hence it is not flat $R-$module and thus above approach is wrong. So projective and flat module part is ruled out. Thank you @Chris H